# how to do less than or equal to and greater than equal to in django filter?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How to do less than or equal to and greater than equal to in django filter? Like , I want to get value around :- `10<=val<=50` in django view.
For this I used some query in sql like this :-

```
select count(*) from table_name where gender='MALE' and age<=50 and age>=10;
```

I tried something like this in django view :-

```
tablename.objects.filter(Q(gender='MALE'),Q(age__lte=50) & Q(age__gte=10)).count()
```

But I got different values. In sql I got 65 and in django I got 29. sql answer is correct. Please help me to do comparison in django view.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Why don't you use the _range function?

`filter(gender='MALE', age__range=(10, 50))`

See here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#range

Edit for new link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#range

Answer (score 22):

If you really want to use `>=` and `<=` yo could write:

```
Modelname.objects.filter(gender='MALE', age__gte = 10, age__lte = 50).count()
```

Comment: i tried your answer its works fine thanks for that.. @doru

Comment: @Irfan wani No, it works on decimals, floats, dates too.

Comment: Thanks for reply.i figured it out. BTW __range is also a better way to do a filter on a range.