# What does this line of code read in plain English?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and Django. I've been playing around with the Django polls tutorial and all is going well but I'm still getting used to the syntax.

What does this line read in plain English?

```
return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
```

The part I'm having trouble with is the <= operator. I'm aware this usually means less than or equal to but I've never seen them being used in succession such as above.

Comment: return whether `pub_date` is between yesterday (24 hours ago) and now.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040143/how-to-do-a-less-than-or-equal-to-filter-in-django-queryset and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743988/how-to-do-less-than-or-equal-to-and-greater-than-equal-to-in-django-filter/34744213.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In short**: it checks if `self.pub_date` is between 24 hours before `now` and `now`.

Python allows [*operator chaining* [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). It means that if you write `x <= y <= z`, that is short for `x <= y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once.

You thus can read this as:

```
return (now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)) <= self.pub_date and self.pub_date <= now
```

Now `now` is likely the current timestamp, so that means that `now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)` is 24 hours before `now`. So in short it checks if `self.pub_date` is between 24 hours before `now` and `now` (both inclusive). If that holds it returns `True`, otherwise it returns `False`.

Likely - although we can not check that - `now` is the current timestamp, so it means if `self.pub_date` is between yesterday (same time) and the current timestamp.